# NestJS cli error: Collection "@nestjs/schematics" cannot be resolved

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to learn NestJS and just following simple tutorial to create nestjs app.

Getting following error while executing cli command **nest new test-project**

NestJS cli Version: 7.1.5
NodeJS Version: v10.18.1

Error:

```
Error: Collection "@nestjs/schematics" cannot be resolved.
at NodeModulesEngineHost.resolve (/Users/tsuthar/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/node-module-engine-host.js:74:19)
at NodeModulesEngineHost._resolveCollectionPath (/Users/tsuthar/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/node-module-engine-host.js:79:37)
at NodeModulesEngineHost.createCollectionDescription (/Users/tsuthar/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/file-system-engine-host-base.js:109:27)
at SchematicEngine._createCollectionDescription (/Users/tsuthar/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:147:40)
at SchematicEngine.createCollection (/Users/tsuthar/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:140:43)
at NodeWorkflow.execute (/Users/tsuthar/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/workflow/base.js:100:41)
at main (/Users/tsuthar/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js:224:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tsuthar/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/bin/schematics.js:315:5)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Failed to execute command: "/Users/tsuthar/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/node_modules/.bin/schematics" @nestjs/schematics:application --name=nestjs-task-management --directory=undefined --no-dry-run --no-skip-git --package-manager=undefined --language="ts" --collection="@nestjs/schematics"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To keep using yarn, this worked for me https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/613#issuecomment-602235328

```
yarn global add @nestjs/schematics
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. same `error` message.
I installed nest with yarn so I use command bellow to add(install) **shematics**:

```
yarn global add @nestjs/schematics
```

If you use npm use this

```
npm i -g @nestjs/schematics
```

Answer (score 2):

Initially, I added NestJS cli with yarn and it gave the above error. 
The issue gets fixed as soon as I've installed NestJS cli with Npm after removing it from yarn.

Answer (score 2):

**What worked for me was 2 lines of code -**

```
yarn add @nestjs/schematics
```

```
nest new your-project-name
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issure recently and none of the suggested issues worked for me. I tried using npm to install @nestjs/cli and also tried to remove @nestjs/cli and reinstall using `yarn global add @nestjs/schematics`.
Finally a hit and trial that did work for me to run the following command using only and only npm

```
npm i -g @nestjs/schematics
```

After this when I tried to create my project using nest new cli command, it worked like a charm. After that you're free to choose and use npm or yarn as per your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when creating a new `nestJS` project with `yarn`. What worked for me is doing the following:

1. Clean yarn cache `yarn cache clean`
2. Remove nest cli `yarn global remove @nestjs/cli`
3. Reinstall nest cli `yarn global add @nestjs/cli`
4. Create new project `nest new project-name`
5. Choose `yarn` when given an option to choose package manager

As @Abderrahmane TAHRI JOUTI mentioned I followed the link and the above solution worked for me.

https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/613#issuecomment-602235328

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error for mine but i was using npm instead of yarn i just updated my node version cause Nestjs uses node version of 12 and above

Answer (score -1):

Install this NPM package works for me,

```
apollo-server-core: 3.7.0
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-core

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.